# Export Table to Excel and Open File

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to export a table (the table is called "Consultations") to Excel, and open the file.  I'm doing this from a form with a button.  At this point, I have the file exporting correctly, but Excel is not staying open.  I tried using `xlApp.Visible = True`, but it is only opening Excel while the file is exported, then it closes Excel when it is done.

What code will I need to insert in order to keep Excel (and the exported file) open?

```
Private Sub btnExportConsultations_Click()

Dim curPath As String
Dim xlApp As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
curPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Consultations - " & Format(Date, "MM") & "-" & Format(Date, "dd") & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & ".xlsx"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Consultations", curPath, -1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the spreadsheet and then use `Application.FollowHyperlink` to open it in the application associated with that file type --- which should be Excel.

```vb
Private Sub btnExportConsultations_Click()
    Dim curPath As String

    curPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Consultations - " & _
        Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Consultations", curPath, -1
    Application.FollowHyperlink curPath 
End Sub
```

Note I also changed the `curPath =` line.  You can get your formatted date into the file name with a single `Format()` expression instead of three.

Comment: Works great!  Thanks for the tip about changing the `curPath =` line to one expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook in the Excel object you created with the Excel application object's [Workbooks.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) method.  Also, I would export the file before messing with Excel - not sure if it makes a difference but I think the code flows better at the very least.

```
Private Sub btnExportConsultations_Click()

    Dim curPath As String
    Dim xlApp As Object

        curPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Consultations - " & Format(Date,"mm-dd-yyyy")
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Consultations", curPath, -1

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open(curPath)
        xlApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```